# How to find a text from database column in a table?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a database in SQL Server in which there is a table with a single column `URL` that contains URL.

I have 1000 rows (supposed).

Now I need to find that which URL contains the text that I will tell.

**Example :**

```
Sr.        URL
1          http://example.com
2          http://example2.com
```

If I have these kind of data and I need to find that which row contains `example2` or simply `2` then I should give me the specific row(s).

Comment: you need to pass the text that you think is the keyword for finding the data. select sr from tablename where url like ('%keytext%')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id from table where URL like ('%example%');
```